Enabling instrumentations in Spring application
I am trying to implement opentelemetry instrumentation in our spring boot applications. I removed sleuth, zipking what ever dependencies and I added dependency io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-spring-boot-starter and added @EnableOpenTelemetry. Also added properties like:
otel:
  sdk:
    disabled: ${OTLP_DISABLED:false}
  exporter:
    otlp:
      endpoint: ${OTLP_ENDPOINT}
      compression: gzip
      protocol: ${OTLP_PROTOCOL:http/protobuf}

as I understand now with these changes I have got basic instrumentation Web and Logback. For instance I have also problem that Tracer can't be injected. Nevertheless my application utilizes Kafka (producer/consumer) over Spring Cloud Streams and Functions, has database connection. I want to be able to see trace from rest call in one application then over kafka into other, etc. What shall I do? Because the topic of enabling of all instrumentations is not really clear described in documentation and slightly wired. For example jdbc: Would adding of dependency io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-jdbc solve issue with instrumenting of jdbc if I use standard spring approach, or I need to do more? Same with Kafka will it work if I just add io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-kafka-clients-2.6 dependency?
Thank you in advance!
